# Cannot import IMDB

Tags: python, imdb

Good evening. I have made a virutalenv in Linux Mint 19. I have installed IMDbPY==6.8. I have my file movie.py in a MyProject folder. When I run python movie.py I get "Cannot Import IMDB".

I found a 2016 thread on here that said to make sure that I did not name the file imdb.py, which I did name it that, but changed it to movie.py. I closed everything and then started back up. Still get the same errors.

I am using Python 3.6.

Here is the file I am trying to run:

```
from imdb import IMDB

# create an instance of the IMDb class
ia = IMDB()

# get a movie and print its director(s)
the_matrix = ia.get_movie('0133093')
for director in the_matrix['directors']:
    print(director['name'])

# show all information that are currently available for a movie
print(sorted(the_matrix.keys()))

# show all information sets that can be fetched for a movie
print(ia.get_movie_infoset())

# update a Movie object with more information
ia.update(the_matrix, ['technical'])
# show which keys were added by the information set
print(the_matrix.infoset2keys['technical'])
# print one of the new keys
print(the_matrix.get('tech'))
```

Here is the traceback:

```
(myenv) chess@chess:~/MyProjects$ python movie.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "movie.py", line 1, in <module>
    from imdb import IMDB
ImportError: cannot import name 'IMDB'
```

The error shows it is on line 1 from *imdb import IMDB* Traceback shows *Cannot import IMDB*

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The last B should be lowercase: `from imdb import IMDb`. It looks like you mis-copied [the example from IMDbPY](https://imdbpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#example).

Comment: Oh,WOW. What a newb mistake. Thank you very much for your help. Have a great evening or day. Thank you again.

Comment: NP, we've all been there :) BTW I'm voting to close the question since the problem was ultimately a typo.

Comment: Consider deleting the question.